# deploy mvc .net framework 4.5

Tags: iis, asp.net-mvc-4, iis-6, web-deployment

I have got MVC website. based on .NET Framework 4.5.
I am trying to deploy the website on IIS 6.0
 
Here are the steps I have taken

1. **Application Pool**:

   I have created application pool: Company.Attendance.
   NOTE: Nowhere it asked me which .NET Version I am using?
2. **Website**

   a.   Create new website.
   b.   Description: company.attendance
   c.   IpAddress: Server Ip Address
   d.   Port: 80
   e.   Host Header for the website:   [I left blank] 
   f.   Path: ../../Views/Home/ [All views are defined here] 
   g.   Permissions: Read, Run, Execute, Write 
   h.  In the website properties, under tab Home Directory I have selected the application pool created above
   i.   In Home Directory TAB, under Configuration.
   j.   I inserted aspnet_iapi.dll

When I try to browse the application. I get the following error: Page cannot be found.

Can one tell me detailed steps to deploy mvc application [.Net Framework 4.5] on IIS 6.0 [Windows Server 2003].

Regards

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to deploy the website on IIS 6.0

You can't. .NET Framework 4.5 requires Windows Server 2008 at least as can be seen in the [`System Requirements page`](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30653):

> System requirements
>
> Supported Operating System
>
> - Windows 7 Service Pack 1
> - Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1
> - Windows Server 2008 Service Pack 2
> - Windows Vista Service Pack 2
> - Windows Vista SP2 (x86 and x64)
> - Windows 7 SP1 (x86 and x64)
> - Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 (x64)
> - Windows Server 2008 SP2 (x86 and x64)
>
> Hardware Requirements:
>
> - 1 GHz or faster processor
> - 512 MB of RAM
> - 850 MB of available hard disk space (x86)
> - 2 GB hard drive (x64)

The latest .NET framework version you could install on Windows Server 2003 is .NET 4.0.

Comment: Thanks Darin for quick answer. This means I am on hold now, till my company provides me with Windows Server 2008.

Comment: Yes, that's what it means.

Answer (score 0):

You need at least IIS 7.0.

Here are the requirements for .NET 4.5 framework: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z6watww%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

You're going to have to use .NET 4.0, which porting your project over shouldn't be too painstaking.

Take your project and change compatibility to 4.0 for framework.
Fix some of the errors, and EF errors you may get, and repush to the IIS 6.0 server.

You need to ensure all the runtimes are installed, and the app is running on the
.NET 4.0 pool.

Answer (score 0):

IIS 6 is part of Windows Server 2003 (and technically XP 64-bit).

.Net 4.5 cannot be installed on Windows Server 2003, thus IIS is not supported.